# Evaluate complete subtree existence of

Tags: xml, xpath

I often want to filter one element using an XPATH expression upon the existence of some element in an entire subtree and I was wondering if it is possible to let an xpath expression match all results. The following expression only evaluates to `true` if it is the first element to match (`Cd[2]` will match but not `Cd[3]`)

```
xpath::evaluate(" //CuorS/Cd[ starts-with(./*/@Name], 'Dog')]")
```

```
<CuorS>
  <Cd>
    <Ani Name="CatOne" />
    <Bodi Name="Fish"  />
  </Cd>
  <Cd>
    <Ani Name="DogOne" />
    <Bodi Name="Fish"  />
  </Cd>
  <Cd>
    <Ani Name="Owl" />
    <Bodi Name="DogTwo"  />
  </Cd>
</CuorS>
```

I know I can formulate the expression as

```
xpath::evaluate("//CuorS/Cd/*[ starts-with(./@Name], 'Dog')]/..")
```

to match all but I'm looking for a filter expression to match existence: 'if there is one matching element in that subtree'. Can I evaluate function on sequences of results and not just one?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

How about that xPath expression:

```
//CuorS/Cd[ count(./*[starts-with(@Name, 'Dog')]) >= 1]
```

This just counts the matching sub nodes (those that a starting with "Dog").
It thus matches every Cd which has at least one sub node matching that condition.

As you can see it gets really easy when you are nesting the condition blocks. By nesting them, you can also do this evaluation of sequences of nodes as you seem to ask for (do not fully understand what you are trying to achieve there).

Here is the output from the xPath (given your sample input):

```
  <Cd> 
    <Ani Name="DogOne"/>  
    <Bodi Name="Fish"/> 
  </Cd>
  <Cd> 
    <Ani Name="Owl"/>  
    <Bodi Name="DogTwo"/> 
  </Cd>
```

Comment: Why count the elements to check if there's something in there? Non-empty sequences evaluate to true.

Comment: Because I like stuff not to surprise people. Yes, empty node lists evaluate to false, non empty ones to true, but this is another piece of knowledge the guy reading this xPath needs to know. Why not make plainly obvious what you mean by writing the condition that you really care about. Keeps it easier for others to figure out what is happening.

Comment: Then better use `not(empty(...))` or something like that, which is more readable and (if not optimized) possibly much faster: `count(...)` requires all items to be calculated, evaluating `empty(...)` or just evaluating it to a boolean value can be stopped after the first match. Anyway: This is a very, very usual pattern used all the time, everybody is using `//foo[bar]` and it's exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Just move the predicate:

```
xpath::evaluate("//CuorS/Cd[*[starts-with(./@Name]], 'Dog')]")
```

This will match all Cd children of CuorS that have a subelement with a name that starts with Dog. Depending on the XPath processor and programming language you're using, you could even evaluate to a boolean value:

```
xpath::evaluate("boolean(//CuorS/Cd[*[starts-with(./@Name]], 'Dog')])")
```

If a result sequence is empty, this will yield false, if there is at least one element it will return true.